# state.Retry is not iterable

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

```
TypeError: state.Retry is not iterable
    at CustomState.toStateJson (/Users/abhiwal/workspace/UpayCore/src/UPayCoreServiceCDK/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions/lib/states/custom-state.js:1:1844)
    at StateGraph.toGraphJson (/Users/abhiwal/workspace/UpayCore/src/UPayCoreServiceCDK/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions/lib/state-graph.js:1:2159)
    at Map.renderIterator (/Users/abhiwal/workspace/UpayCore/src/UPayCoreServiceCDK/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions/lib/states/state.js:1:7229)
    at Map.toStateJson (/Users/abhiwal/workspace/UpayCore/src/UPayCoreServiceCDK/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions/lib/states/map.js:1:1474)
    at StateGraph.toGraphJson (/Users/abhiwal/workspace/UpayCore/src/UPayCoreServiceCDK/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions/lib/state-graph.js:1:2159)
    at ChainDefinitionBody.bind (/Users/abhiwal/workspace/UpayCore/src/UPayCoreServiceCDK/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions/lib/state-machine.js:1:12008)
    at new StateMachine (/Users/abhiwal/workspace/UpayCore/src/UPayCoreServiceCDK/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions/lib/state-machine.js:1:6368)
    at InvoiceBatchesLambdaExecutor.createStateMachine (/Users/abhiwal/workspace/UpayCore/src/UPayCoreServiceCDK/dist/lib/workflows/invoice-batches-lambda-executor.js:16:16)
    at new InvoiceBatchesLambdaExecutor (/Users/abhiwal/workspace/UpayCore/src/UPayCoreServiceCDK/dist/lib/workflows/invoice-batches-lambda-executor.js:13:34)
    at new WorkflowStack (/Users/abhiwal/workspace/UpayCore/src/UPayCoreServiceCDK/dist/lib/stacks/workflow-stack.js:22:45)

Node.js v18.19.1

Subprocess exited with error 1
 ›   Error: Failed to run CDK CLI
```

I am getting this error while doing cdkv2 migration for my service. I am using "aws-cdk-lib":"^2.118.0" version in my package.json?

Comment: Next time please post sample code!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/29274) that was fixed in a [recent release](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/releases/tag/v2.133.0). Try updating to `2.133.0`.